# Mapbox not updating after changes made in source data

Tags: amazon-s3, d3.js, aws-lambda, mapbox-gl-js, squarespace

This is my first time attempting code and asking for help so please go easy on me :) I have a website (using Squarespace) where users submit information through a form that is then populated on a google sheet. Following a tutorial from Mapbox called SheetMapper Advanced, I've used AWS and S3 to cache the data from the google sheet. From here, I've created an HTML code using D3 library to transform the data into markers on a map through MapBox. Initial upload went fine; however, when I tested submitting additional entries through the site, they are populated on the google sheet, but not the Mapbox on the site. In short, it appears only initial upload made it to the map.

I've checked the CORS and S3 permissions in AWS, everything follows the tutorial linked here: https://labs.mapbox.com/education/impact-tools/sheetmapper-advanced/#add-your-mapbox-access-token. Note that the tutorial video instructs selecting "Put Bucket Acl" for the permissions; however, the tutorial word version indicates "Put Object Acl" so I went with that one. I've checked that the google sheets are visible to those that have the link.

Any ideas?

Code below for reference. I've put placeholders for my inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Replace with your title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #404040;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-close-button {
      display: none;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-content {
      font: 400 15px/22px "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Sans-serif;
      padding: 0;
      width: 250px;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-content-wrapper {
      padding: 1%;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-content h3 {
      background: rgb(61, 59, 59);
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      display: block;
      padding: 15px;
      font-weight: 700;
      margin-top: -5px;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-content h4 {
      background: rgb(61, 59, 59);
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 3px 10px 10px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    .mapboxgl-container {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-content {
      margin-top: 3px;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
      border-bottom-color: rgb(61, 59, 59);
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var transformRequest = (url, resourceType) => {
        var isMapboxRequest =
          url.slice(8, 22) === "api.mapbox.com" ||
          url.slice(10, 26) === "tiles.mapbox.com";
        return {
          url: isMapboxRequest
            ? url.replace("?", "?pluginName=sheetMapper&")
            : url,
        };
      };

      //YOUR TURN: add your Mapbox token
      mapboxgl.accessToken =
        '<INSERT TOKEN>';     //Mapbox token
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', //stylesheet location
    center: [-86.81686, 36.10207], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9, // starting zoom
    transformRequest: transformRequest,
  });

  map.on("load", function () {
    init();
  });

  // YOUR TURN: Add the link to your shared spreadsheet to allow D3 to access your table
  function init() {
    d3.csv(
      '<INSERT SOURCE CSV>',
      addPoints
    );
  }

  // create a function called addPoints that iterates through your table (row by row) to create markers and popups
  function addPoints(data) {
    // iterate through your table to set the marker to lat/long values for each row

    data.forEach(function (row) {
      // create a variable for your popup and populate your popup with information from your table
      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(
        `<h3>` +
          row.city +
          `</h3>` +
          "<h4>" +
          "<b>" +
          "Other: " +
          "</b>" +
          row.Other +
          "</h4>" +
          "<h4>" +
          "<b>" +
          "Start: " +
          "</b>" +
          row.Start +
          "</h4>"
      ); // use the table to populate your popup with text
      
      // create a variable for your markup and add it to the map
      var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        color: "purple",
      })
        .setLngLat([row.Longitude, row.Latitude])
        .setPopup(popup)
        .addTo(map); // add the marker to the map
    });
  }
</script>
```